# Is it possible to find an inverse system for this difference equation?

Tags: signal-processing

y[n] = x[2n + 1] + x[2n − 1]

I know that a system is invertible if none of two inputs results in the same output. In my opinion two such inputs exist so this system is not invertible since any number of x[n] can be a found which satisfy x[n]+x[n-2]=y[(n-1)/2] . But I am not sure whether I am right or not.

Comment: Look up the book called Concrete Mathematics and generating functions to solve recurrences.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it is not invertible so there is no such an inverse system. Do I need to solve this difference equation in order to show it is not invertible ? Or is there no way to determine whether it is invertible other than solving it ?

Comment: I didn't want to disagree or agree with your statement. I merely wanted to refer you to a text and topic areas which I believe relate. Your call, though.

Comment: are you sure this is your system? It's anticausal, and that's usually not a good sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think of your system in simpler terms. Assume \$x[2n + 1] = a\$ and \$x[2n − 1] = b\$. Therefore:

$$
y = a+b
$$

Can you find a unique solution for both \$a\$ and \$b\$, knowing only the value \$y\$ ? The answer is no, there are infinte possible solutions. However, if you absolutely must find an inverse, constraints could be added to the problem, so that we have new probabilistic possibilities.

Are \$x[2n + 1]\$ and \$x[2n - 1]\$ completely independent from each other, or is there some correlation? Is \$x\$ limited in amplitude or bandwidth? Perhaps a stochastic process can describe it? If enough constraints can be brought to the problem, one could then find an "expected" value for \$a\$ and \$b\$.

For example, say \$x\$ is described by a gaussian stochastic process, with mean \$\mu\$. Then the expected answer would be the one which brings both \$a\$ and \$b\$ closest to \$\mu\$.

One must realize that the system must then be solved for all \$n\$ in your considered range (do you wish to find solution \$\forall n \geq 0\$ ?). In this particular problem, this means solving:

$$
y[0] = x[1] + x[-1]\\
y[1] = x[3] + x[1]\\
y[2] = x[5] + x[3] \\
\dots
$$

If by some constraint or known value, you can find \$x[-1]\$, then you can solve for \$x[1]\$ and \$x[3]\$ and all others \$x[2n+1]\$.

In sum: is the system invertible? In strict terms, no. Is it possible to find an expected inverse signal? Given sufficient constraints, yes.